# multisig request

Tags: multisig

we have a request for a multisig. if someone could implement it, then we would be ready to pay for it. we need a fully working product.

what was presented not so long ago still does not work [https://tzsignwallet.com](https://tzsignwallet.com/), it has been more than half a year, and there is still no result.

I do not know why this cannot be implemented until now.
if someone was ready to implement it, then we could agree on the price of the issue.

Comment: the testnet seems to be working.
but the main network is already needed

OK

Answer (score 1):

The wallet included in the [OCaml Tezos Distribution](http://tezos.gitlab.io/user/multisig.html) contains native support for a multisig contract. There is commands for deploying a multisig and interacting with it. The specific documentation for these commands is [here](http://tezos.gitlab.io/user/multisig.html). Feel free to submit more questions if you have more specific inquiries.